# How to decrypt keystore password on Connector in Tomcat 8.5.16

Tags: tomcat8, password-encryption

I have defined my Connector in tomcat 7 style:

```
<Connector
   port="443"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   protocol="nl.messagedesign.tomcatlib.EncryptedPassword_Http11Nio2Protocol"
   scheme="https"
   secure="true"
   SSLEnabled="true"
   sslProtocol="TLS"
   clientAuth="false"
   keystoreFile="C:/Users/Maarten/Certificaten/gm_messagedesign_nl.jks"
   keystorePass="NB8WGQyivc1IhbdxzGE9ew=="/>
```

and in Tomcat 8.5 style

```
<Connector
   port="443"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   protocol="nl.messagedesign.tomcatlib.EncryptedPassword_Http11Nio2Protocol"
   scheme="https"
   secure="true"
   SSLEnabled="true"
   defaultSSLHostConfigName="gm.messagedesign.nl">
   <SSLHostConfig
       certificateVerification="none"
       hostName="gm.messagedesign.nl"
       sslProtocol="TLS">
       <Certificate 
           certificateKeystoreFile="C:/Users/Maarten/Certificaten/gm_messagedesign_nl.jks"
           certificateKeystorePassword="NB8WGQyivc1IhbdxzGE9ew=="
           certificateKeystoreType="JKS"/>
   </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Starting tomcat 8.5.16 everything works as expected with the Tomcat 7 style connector, but with the tomcat 8.5 style connector I get the error message that the keystore authentication failed.

The relevant java code for the class nl.messagedesign.tomcatlib.EncryptedPassword_Http11Nio2Protocol is

```
public class EncryptedPassword_Http11Nio2Protocol extends Http11NioProtocol {

public EncryptedPassword_Http11Nio2Protocol () {
    super ();
    }

@Override
public void setKeystorePass (String s) {
        super.setKeystorePass (PaswoordEncryptionUtils.get ().decrypt (s));
    }
}
```

Debugging with the Tomcat 7 style connector shows that the constructor and setKeystorePass () are called. Debugging with the Tomcat 8.5 style connector only the constructor is called and not setKeystorePass ().

Any help explaining the unexpected behaviour of the tomcat 8.5 style Connector will be appreciated.